# Query list of partitions (and/or partition key values) in DocumentDB

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I am using a partitioned collection for as persistence solution.

I am searching for a way to list number of partitions I have and get partition key value for each of them in a collection. But I could not find anything from .NET SDK to achieve this. Could you please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I could not find anything from .NET SDK to achieve this. Could you please help?

I have checked with [Microsoft Azure DocumentDB Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB) and you could leverage [DocumentClient.ReadPartitionKeyRangeFeedAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.readpartitionkeyrangefeedasync.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for getting Partition key ranges. Additionally, for the similar issue, you could leverage [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) to check the SDK library for the related Request URI for the specific REST API.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the list of partition key ranges (physical partitions) using the `Get Partition Key Ranges` AI in DocumentDB: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/get-partition-key-ranges