# Query cosmosdb using partition key

Tags: java, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have an employee dto with department as partitionKey.

1. How to get number of partition at any given of point of time?
2. How to query cosmosdb(documentDB) using partitionKey, either query explorer or java api will do?

What I tried:

```
List<Document> documentList = documentClient.queryDocuments(getCollection().getSelfLink(),"SELECT * FROM root r WHERE r.partitionKey ='" + partitionKey+"'", null).getQueryIterable().toList();
```

I end up getting **IllegalStateException** state exception from java api and query exporter also did't give any output. Any help is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Partial answer:

Given the name of `Partition Key` attribute is `department`, please change your query to:

```
List<Document> documentList = 
    documentClient.queryDocuments(
         getCollection().getSelfLink(),
              "SELECT * FROM root r WHERE r.department ='" + 
              partitionKey + "'", null).getQueryIterable().toList();
```

Comment: thanks much @gaurav, is there a way to get number of partition at any given point of time?

Comment: Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43319308/query-list-of-partitions-and-or-partition-key-values-in-documentdb. Let me know if it helps and I will include it in the answer.

Comment: I hope `partitionKey` is not a user controllable input because this is vulnerable to `SQLi` if it comes from the user

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve the same thing by providing the link to collection

```
List<Document> documentList = documentClient.queryDocuments("/dbs/<yourdbname>/colls/<collectionname>","SELECT * FROM root r WHERE r.department ='" + partitionKey+"'", null).getQueryIterable().toList();
```